# Restore MongoDb archive from Atlas with mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, restore, mongorestore

I downloaded a backup **restore-xxx.tar.gz** from my mongodb atlas (online download link)

I want to restore it on an other server with this command

```
.\mongorestore.exe -uri mongodb+srv://xxx-xxx.mongodb.net --username xxxx --password 'xxxx' --nsFrom='xxxxx.*' --nsTo='restoreDbTest.*' --gzip --archive='D:\MongoExportData\restore-xxx.tar.gz'
```

I tried unzip tar achive too same result :

```
.\mongorestore.exe -uri mongodb+srv://xxx-xxx.mongodb.net --username xxxx --password 'xxxx' --nsFrom='xxxxx.*' --nsTo='restoreDbTest.*' --gzip --archive='D:\MongoExportData\unzip-***.gz'
```

I got this error :

```
2020-10-30T11:41:24.494+0100    Failed: stream or file does not appear to be a mongodump archive
2020-10-30T11:41:24.495+0100    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Can you explain why i can't restore atlas backup with the mongorestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

How to export and restore mongoDb between two mongo Atlas account:

1. Download archive from mongo Atlas
2. Extract the tar
3. Run doemons (Be sure service not running on windows) => `'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.exe' --dbpath D:\MongoExportArchive\restore-5f7431d95f8089221b1e16dd`
4. Create dump and save in D:/data ==> `'D:\MongoTools\bin\mongodump.exe' -d myDataBase -o D:\Data`
5. Import Dump with mongorestore ==> `'D:\MongoTools\bin\mongorestore.exe' -uri mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net -d dbRestoreProd --username myUser --password 'myP4ss0rd' D:\Data\myDataBase`